# Replace a specific URL on all apperances on the Website (Maybe a filter?)

Tags: filters

I'm stuck with this problem:

The Plugin "Lazy Load - Optimize Images" is doing a great job lazy loading YouTube-Videos but is automatically using a preview picture from the YouTube-Server. The Server ist very slow and when I show a Video above the fold it really drags the page speed insights rating down.

Is there a way to replace the URL manually after the plugin created it's part of the html-code? Like a filter I can use? Of course I know the URL-String i want to replace..

(The creator of the plugin didn't provide a solution for that question in the support forum, so I'm hoping for a solution from you guys ;-) ).

Edit: This is the code, that i want to change:

```
<div data-id="89KRyVaCkbQ" data-query="feature=oembed" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/89KRyVaCkbQ"><img loading="lazy" alt="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/89KRyVaCkbQ/hqdefault.jpg" class="lazyloaded" data-ll-status="loaded" width="480" height="360"><noscript><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" width="480" height="360"></noscript><div class="play"></div></div>
```

Comment: How are you including the video - with an oEmbed? Is the URL it's loading actually in your site, or is it supplied by YouTube over an API. And I'd be very surprised if YouTube's server was slow.

Comment: hi! Thank you for your answer.The YouTube-Server ist actually a lot slower than my hoster - at least for that preview picture. It shows in the Browsers Inspector/Network Tab.

Comment: <div data-id="89KRyVaCkbQ" data-query="feature=oembed" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/89KRyVaCkbQ"><img loading="lazy" alt="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/89KRyVaCkbQ/hqdefault.jpg" class="lazyloaded" data-ll-status="loaded" width="480" height="360"><noscript><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" width="480" height="360"></noscript><div class="play"></div></div>

Comment: The Video is embedded in Gutenberg but the output is altered by the plugin. I want to change the "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/89KRyVaCkbQ/hqdefault.jpg" part.

Comment: :-) The Author actually did deliver a workarout. So,problem solved :-)